# vuex module namespace not found in mapActions(): taskModule/?

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component, state, vuex

Hello my application starts growing so i decided to call in vuex(for the first time) but i can't get it to work when i call actions/mutations of a module

my taskModule

```
const state = () => ({
    newTask : false,
    tasks: []
})

const getters = {}

const actions = {
    test() {
        console.log('EYOOO IT WORKSS')
      },
}

const mutations = {}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

my store

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import taskModule from '../store/modules/tasks'
export default createStore({
  state: {    
    taskModule
  },
})
```

my component js

```
export default {
  components: {
    Button,
    TaskList,
    NewTask,
  },
  computed: mapState({
    newTask: (state) => state.taskModule.state().newTask,
    tasks: (state) => state.taskModule.state().tasks,
  }),

  methods: {
    ...mapActions("taskModule",["test"]),
    newTask(val) {
      this.$store.dispatch("taskModule/test")
      console.log(val);
    },
  },
};
```

when i call newTask i get the error

Comment: You have both a computed and a  method called `newTask`

Comment: ouch true! i changed it...but i still get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a module you need to change :

```js
export default createStore({
  state: {    
    taskModule
  },
})
```

To :

```js
export default createStore({
  modules: {    
    taskModule
  },
})
```

https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

Comment: GOAT (why i never read the docs carefully)